# why is the return not working and giving wrong values in the output

Tags: python, function

im trying to make a function in python that tell you how many days are in each month but when i test it gives wrong values for example for april it should say 30 but it returns none

heres the code :
def month_days(m):

```
if m == 1 and m == 3 and m == 5 and m == 7 and m == 8 and m == 10 and m == 12 :
    return 31 
elif m == 4 and m == 6 and m == 9 and m == 11 :
    return 30 
elif m ==2 :
    return 28 
elif m > 12 : 
    return -1
```

here the output :
Checking for month number 4, should return 30
WRONG: April has 30 days but the code returned None

Comment: You need OR, not AND

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything if none of the conditions are True. You want `or` though. If you think about it, how would `m` be equal to `4` and `6` at the same time?

Comment: put all these numbers in a list and check if m is in list.

Comment: you could also just write as `if m in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:`

Answer (score 0):

`m` can't be multiple things at once. you have to use `or`. What you want to do can be done easier:

```
def month_days(m):
    if m < 1 or m > 12:
        return -1
    if m == 2:
        return 28
    if m in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
        return 30
    return 31
```

When one of these conditions is met, the function will return a value so you don't need to use `elif`. And you can just delete the first `if` and instead put a `return 31` at the end, as `else`.

Answer (score 0):

As aaronn mentions, there is a logic error in your code. Here is a link that will help you get more familiar with programming logic, and understanding logical AND, OR, IF, ELSE, and compares (==, !=, >, <): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_programming/computer_programming_operators.htm
There operators are the basis of functional and object oriented programming.